# Mergext, Mergbanner features and setup

Tags: ios, livecode

I was all geared up to sign up for an app monetisation account with inner-active for livecode but have since found out that livecode don't use them anymore.
They simply sent me a link for MergExt and said "use that".

Can anyone tell me how it works? How do I register an account to get payment from the ads displayed? Does this all work automatically through my apple developer account or do I have to set up a specific account? Suddenly I'm a bit lost and I've been given no information which is frustrating.

I'd really appreciate some guidance from anyone who has already set theirs up. My app is for iOS so I'm open to any suggestions on inserting ads using livecode.
Thanks
Dave :)

Comment: Have you looked at livecode for any help on the problem? http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/68315-how-do-i-use-ads-in-livecode

Comment: Hi, Thanks for asking. I had a look but everything seems to relate to inneractive who livecode no longer work with.

Answer (score 0):

The mergExt external [mergBanner](http://mergext.com/mergbanner) implements iAd banner and interstitial views so everything you need to know caan be gleaned from either the documentation and demo that comes with mergBanner or [Apple's iAd documentation](https://developer.apple.com/iad/monetize/)

Comment: I've downloaded the mergExt banner extension with associated files but I can't seem to get the livecode demo to work. I've uploaded it to my phone but no ads appearing. Any tips?